# How to get Closure Compiler to ignore JSDoc annotations?

Tags: google-closure-compiler

One of the 15 or so JavaScript files I'm combining using the Google Closure Compiler contains the tag `@license WTFPL` in one of its comments.

As a result, the Closure Compiler labels our *entire* set of JavaScript as if it were *all* licensed under WTFPL.

Obviously this is undesirable - even if just because we *can't* relicense much of this code under WTFPL. How can I turn this off?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found **re-running the closure compiler on the compiled output** will get rid of the comment block containing the license.

Not sure if this would be desired in your case, but in mine (minifying a set of [jQuery Tools](http://jquerytools.org/) scripts) it worked well and I didn't need any other manipulation.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing built in that will do that.  Your options are:

- change the @licence tag to something else
- change the comment type from jsdoc to a standard comment
- modify the compiler source
- preprocess the source (replacing "@license" with "_license" would be reasonable)
- postprocess the output (removing the problematic license text)

Comment: Postprocess the output seems to be the most realistic option, since I don't want to modify third-party files to ease updating them to newer versions.